# Deploy Node Express API via Docker Compose on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my EC2, I pulled my Docker images from my ECR : `API` + `WEB`

I then start both of them up via Docker Compose

[image]

It seems to start fine, but I don't know why I can't seem to go to my API.

I can go to my site

[image]

When I go to my API, I see this

[image]

I already open up the `3002` port on my `EC2` inbound rule

[image]

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  iproject-api:
    image: '616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api-script:latest'
    ports:
      - '3002:3002'
  iproject-web:
    image: '616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-web-script:latest'
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
    links:
      - iproject-api
```

Did I forgot to restart any service?

Answer (score 0):

Inbound rule looks fine. Check your API code status in EC2 `docker logs {API_Container_Id}/telnet localhost 3002`